# IF formula doesn't understand cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have a basic IF formula,

```
'=SI(BH138<>"";BH138;BG138)
```

But the "IF NOT" case seems to not work,

It act like BH is not blank.

I did a LEN formula to know it, it marks "1".

My formula in BH is a basic INDEX MATCH.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(STT!F:F,MATCH($A2,STT!$A:$A,0),0),"")
```

How can it be possible to have 1 char ?

[image: Exemple]

Comment: What do you mean by seems to not work? Do you also have the single quote in front of the formula, or is that a typo in the question?

Comment: Or is formula calculation set to manual instead of automatic?

Comment: Not enough information to answer the question. One possible explanation is that cell `BH139` might actually not be blank (e.g. it might have a single space), which would result in the condition `BH139<>""` being true, thus returning `BH139`. Another possibility although probably not likely is that the cells are formatted with white text and white background.

Comment: Yes, BH seems not be blank. There is a formula Inside. I will edit my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems to have 1 char in the blank cells,

I edited my formula as it :

```
=SI(NBCAR(BH2)>1;BH2;BG2)
```

It's ugly but it works, for now...

Answer (score -1):

There is a whitespace in front of the = which makes excel treat your cell as a string instead of a function. To correct the error, remove the whitespace in front of the function.
Also if there is an apostrophe in front excel will treat it as a string.
Remove the apostrophe.